# How to stop Java after processing Open Office documents

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am using Java to create and edit Open Office documents. However, after modifying the documents, Java does not exit and still runs many threads, such as Thread [Pipe: CO>], Thread [Pipe: CE>] and Thread [MessageDispatcher]. I would like to be able to close these threads and allow Java to close when the code is done.

Here is my code for opening and closing documents:

```
private static Object oDesktop;
private static XStorable xStorable;
private static XComponent xSpreadsheetComponent;
private static XComponentContext xContext;
private static XSpreadsheetDocument xSpreadsheetDocument;
private static XSpreadsheets xSpreadsheets;

    public static void openDocument(String filename)
    {
    try
    {           
        // Get the remote office component context
        xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap();

        // Get the remote office service manager
        XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();

        // Get the root frame (i.e. desktop) of openoffice framework.
        oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);

        // Desktop has 3 interfaces. The XComponentLoader interface provides ability to load components.
        XComponentLoader xCompLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class,
                oDesktop);

        PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[0];

        xSpreadsheetComponent = xCompLoader.loadComponentFromURL(getUpdatedPath(filename), "_blank", 0, loadProps);

        xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xSpreadsheetComponent);

        xSpreadsheetDocument = (XSpreadsheetDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSpreadsheetDocument.class,
                xSpreadsheetComponent);

        xSpreadsheets = xSpreadsheetDocument.getSheets();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void closeDocument()
{
    try
    {
        XCloseable xCloseable = (XCloseable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCloseable.class, xStorable);

        if (xCloseable != null)
        {
            xCloseable.close(false);
        }
        else
        {
            XComponent xComp = (XComponent) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponent.class, xStorable);

            xComp.dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it a standalone program?

Comment: I am using Eclipse to run the code, if that is what you are asking :).

Comment: I mean, does it have a main method?

Comment: Good point, forgot to mention it. It is part of another (lengthy) function that basically only performs operations like OpenDocument, CloseDocument and cell editing. That function does not run as a separate thread (does not extend Thread or the Runnable interface).

Comment: It might help to post the relevant parts of your main method.  If you look at the BookmarkInsertion example from [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java), it ends in `System.exit(0);`  Also is there a reason why all of the variables need to be static?  That doesn't seem like it would allow them to be destroyed properly.

Comment: Thank you sir for your post! That actually answers my question (so you can change it to an answer and I will accept it :) ). I did use System.exit(0), but I thought it was bad code, however, if the documentation uses it :). Also, good point on the static variables, will look at that closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comment, in the BookmarkInsertion example from https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java, the code ends in `System.exit(0);`.

Also, is there a reason why all of the variables need to be static?  That doesn't seem like it would allow them to be destroyed properly.